# MPMoviePlayerController and HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

every one. I'm trying to figure out how to play live stream using MPMoviePlayerController. For testing i'm using Apples test stream sample http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbopall.html.
It's perfectly working in UIWebView, but i can't make it work with MPMoviePlayerController. There is my piece of code:

```
NSURL *mediaURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbopall.html"];
MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:mediaURL];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                           object:nil]; 

[mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
[mp setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming];
[mp setFullscreen:YES];

[self.view addSubview:[mp view]];

[mp prepareToPlay];
[mp play];
```

Actually the controller recieves MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification without playing anything. Where is the problem?

Comment: "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer'"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your problem is probably with the URL. `MPMoviePlayerController` wants the URL directly to the file you want to play. You are providing the URL for an `HTML` page which the movie player doesn't understand. That is why it does work in `UIWebView` since a web browser understands `HTML`. If you want more information about what's wrong you can check the error doing the following, quoted from Apple's documentation:

> To check for errors in URL loading,
>   register for the
>   MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification
>   or
>   MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
>   notifications. On error, these
>   notifications contain an NSError
>   object available using the @"error"
>   key in the notification’s userInfo
>   dictionary.

It would look something like:

```
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSError *error = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Did finish with error: %@", error);
    }
}
```

If you want to try and play that sample you can try and access the URL for the stream directly, which would be: http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8

Comment: Thanks a lot - the url was the real problem. One more question: MPMoviePlayerController - is this the right choice to play live audio stream (like internet radio)? I searched for the ways of implementing HTTP Live Streaming and came to the conclusion that MoviePlayer was the thing i needed.

Comment: You're welcome. I have not done any streaming myself so I can't comment on which approach is the best.

Answer (score 5):

You should use direct link to play list file: http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8

```
NSURL *mediaURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"];
MPMoviePlayerController *mediaPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:mediaURL];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `object:mp` instead of `object:nil` in your `NSNotification`

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew:

Here is Apple documentation of HTTP Live Streaming including sample code http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/search/index.php?Search=HTTP+Live+Streaming+Overview

Dung.