# MPMoviePlayerController and HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: iphone, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am working on 1 iphone app that need to be show video which loads from the internet by using HTTP Streaming . I am searching the ways to do it but I did not get any up to now. 
Can anybody help in this .
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [MPMoviePlayerController and HTTP Live Streaming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302383/mpmovieplayercontroller-and-http-live-streaming)

Answer (score 0):

This guide from Apple should help:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick response , I saw that link and not understanding what need to do exactly .