# load videos to play on iPhone from MySQL using php Webservice

Tags: iphone, ipad, video, video-streaming

Can any one please guide me on this . I am new to iphone/ipad programming.I store videos on my webserver (apache/php).I need to write code for an ipad app to get the videos list for a selected user and play those videos on the ipad/iphone using a php webservice.I was not able to get going on this.Please can anybody share any related links or shower your thoughts on this ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

your question actually involves a lot to implement, but I'm not sure where you're right now:

1. Sever-side programming to expose web-service which can be invoked to
   get a list of available videos. Have you done this? And what format
   your server-side responses, SOAP XML or JSON?
2. From your iOS client side, you firstly need to establish an HTTP
   request to the web-service URL entry. Have you done that? You may
   want to use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to save your effort.
3. Once you've got server response, depending on how the data is
   presented, you may need to find a XML parser or a JSON parser to
   parse the raw response.
4. Then you need to either download the video entirely before playback,
   or stream the playback. You may again need [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) for
   downloading. You may need MPMoviePlayerViewController or
   MPMoviePlayerController(if you want more control over the player layout) to plackback/stream the video, see:
   [MPMoviePlayerController and HTTP Live Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302383/mpmovieplayercontroller-and-http-live-streaming)
5. And don't forget to save the playlist and user viewing history if
   you want to provide a smooth user experience. You may use as simple
   as NSUserDefaults/plist as the data persistence media, or as complex
   as SQLite database or Core Data.

I suggest you to break down your ultimate goal into specific tasks, and tackle them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Program your web server to return a JSON object with the list of
   movies. You can include preview thumbnails etc.
2. Include one of the JSON frameworks available (just do a quick
   search, there are plenty).
3. Use the data from the JSON feed to display your list.
4. When the user clicks on an item, launch a view controller with a
   `UIWebView` to display your movies.

If you do not know how to do any of these things, you should consider an objective-C programming tutorial first.