# Streaming video over HTTP in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I am am working on my app.which have requirement play video  on iPhone by server. I have a video link http://www.cwtmedia.se/cwtvideo.mp4 . Can any body suggest me how i perform this on MPMoviePlayerController.I am using this code for that but its not working.

```
enter code here


NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"http://www.cwtmedia.se/cwtvideo.mp4"];
moviePlayer1 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer1.view];
moviePlayer1.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 416); 
moviePlayer1.fullscreen=YES;
[moviePlayer1 setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
moviePlayer1.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;

[moviePlayer1 play];
```

Comment: have you searched for stackoverflow for this problem?
check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864405/play-video-stream-with-mpmovieplayercontroller and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302383/mpmovieplayercontroller-and-http-live-streaming plz..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by the way here's how i use mpmovieplayercontroller for streaming :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:videoUrl];
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];
moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
CGRect frame;
if(self.interfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    frame = CGRectMake(20, 69, 280, 170);
else if(self.interfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || self.interfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    frame = CGRectMake(20, 61, 210, 170);
[moviePlayer.view setFrame:frame];  // player's frame must match parent's
[self.view addSubview: moviePlayer.view];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:moviePlayer.view];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayer];

[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[moviePlayer play];
```

and then here's the delegate method :

```
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
       MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
            removeObserver:self
            name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
            object:player];

       if ([player respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)]){
          //self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
          [player.view removeFromSuperview];
       }
}
```

hope this will help you..

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you have 2 options:

1) First download the file and play it locally. Like this:

```
   NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cwtvideo" ofType:@"mp4"];
   MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
```

2) Use the HTTP streaming protocol. As far as I know [HTTP streaming](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) is the only streaming protocol known by the MPMoviePlayerController.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!