# iOS - How to stream video from a media server?

Tags: ios, stream, media, nas, tvos

I am attempting to create a simple iOS/tvOS app that will allow me to stream video from my Seagate Media Central server (NAS) that has a ton of local video files (mp4, mkv, avi, etc.).

I have so far been able to successfully do the following:

1. Use Bonjour to discover all network devices.
2. Traverse through the media server's folders and list all files/directories in them and parse them into full paths to the files.

Now I am having an issue figuring out how to actually play the video files since it is neither a local app file or a true HTTP remote file.

For simplicity, lets assume I am just going to play .mp4 files (but if you have a solution that can also play mkv/avi/etc then feel free to recommend!). 
I tried using AVPlayer with the full url path (both ftp and http) to the file, but it doesn't work:

```
ftp://seagate.local/Public/Movies/Avengers.mp4
http://seagate.local/Public/Movies/Avengers.mp4
```

I have also tried including my username/password in the URL, as this is required when I connect to my media server on Mac OS via Finder, but still no such luck:

```
http://myuser:mypassword@seagate.local/Public/Movies/Avengers.mp4
```

I have dug around and it looks like maybe CFReadStream is the answer, but Apple's sample code is confusing and cumbersome (not to mention my app is all in Swift and their code is in outdated objective-c), so I am hoping someone can help point me in the right direction.

Comment: Always had impression that the standard media player component should be able to handle urls like this.

Comment: @Umka I am guessing its related to the media server and potentially needing authentication of some kind (i.e. When I connect to the media server via Mac Finder, I am required to enter my username and password). I tried updating the url to be "http://username:password@seagate.local/Public/Movies/Avengers.mp4" but still no luck...

Comment: I suggest you to figure out the principle ability to play something over ftp/http without auth needs. Then you could try to look at auth. So make sure you have no auth and try to play it. Simplest possible way would be to feed it some url and call play(). Sorry, not familiar with this API in IOS but in android it works exactly like this. More complex way would be to code streaming (reading chunk-by-chunk) yourself and feed it into some kind of input stream or pipe. This should be tried only after substantial effort with reading manuals, when you really have no other choice. Good luck!

Comment: Seems to be answered (at least partially) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499312/streaming-video-over-http-in-ios